# Importing an objective-c enum from a swift file?

Tags: swift, objective-c, enums

I'm trying to import an objective-c enum to use in a swift file. To do so, my enum is defined as follows:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UBESearchType) {
    UBESearchTypeGlobal = 0,
    UBESearchTypeInStoreSearch = 1
};
```

In my swift file I import the library it correponds to: `import LegacyModelsObjc`.
I try referencing the enum `UBESearchTypeGlobal` but I get an error which says `Cannot find UBESearchTypeGlobal in scope`. Any idea why this error might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fool.
In swift you need to specify the namespace of the enum rather than the name of it.

So I had to do `UBESearchType.global` to access it